# Vuejs2 router in template: How can I fix the 'recognized expression: #/' issue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

This happens when I try to use vue-router in template with vue 2... Can anyone can help me?

```
recognized expression: #/
    at fa.error (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:12556)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:18609)
    at fa.select (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:21417)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:7143)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:23932)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:24485)
    at n (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:405)
    at main.js:149:20
```

Comment: The error is not enough to fully understand the cause.  Please post your code showing how you added vue-router to your app, your router config, and the relevant component code where you tried to use routing.  Also, are you sure the error wasn't **un**recongized expression?  "recognized" doesn't really make sense as an error